# Is there a way to query all custom post type tags and return the slug of each?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, slug, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to query all custom post type tags and return the slug of each?

This is my current code which return the tag name:

```
$current_article_tags = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_hub_tag', array('fields' => 'names'));
```

I tried changing name to slug with no success:

```
$current_article_tags = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_hub_tag', array('fields' => 'slug'));
```

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because you have a typo :P You need to use `slugs`, not `slug`. See: [WP_Term_Query::_construct() parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is almost there. In order to get just the slugs I suggest you wrap the `wp_get_object_terms` function as follows.

```
function get_object_term_slugs($object_id, $taxonomy){
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($object_id, $taxonomy);
    return array_map(function($term){
        return $term->slug;
    }, $terms);
}

$current_article_slugs = get_object_term_slugs(get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_hub_tag');
```